# How to run permutations using mclapply in a reproducible way regardless of number of threads and OS?

Tags: r

Is is possible to run some permutation-based function using mclapply in a reproducible way regardless of number of threads and OS?
Below is a toy example.  Hashing of the resulting list of permutated vectors is just for convenience of comparing the results.  I tried different `RNGkind` ("L'Ecuyer-CMRG"), different settings for `mc.preschedule` and `mc.set.seed`. So far no luck to make them all identical.

```
library("parallel")
library("digest")

set.seed(1)
m <- mclapply(1:10, function(x) sample(1:10),
              mc.cores=2, mc.set.seed = F)
digest(m, 'crc32')

set.seed(1)
m <- mclapply(1:10, function(x) sample(1:10),
              mc.cores=4, mc.set.seed = F)
digest(m, 'crc32')

set.seed(1)
m <- mclapply(1:10, function(x) sample(1:10),
              mc.cores=2, mc.set.seed = F)
digest(m, 'crc32')

set.seed(1)
m <- mclapply(1:10, function(x) sample(1:10),
              mc.cores=1, mc.set.seed = F)
digest(m, 'crc32')

set.seed(1)
m <- lapply(1:10, function(x) sample(1:10))
digest(m, 'crc32') # this is equivalent to what I get on Windows.
```

`sessionInfo()` just in case:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] digest_0.6.8

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.0
```

Comment: I ran into a similar problem at work. Ultimately, our solution was to set the seed within the function based on a value of the data being referenced (so you might set the seed based on the current value of x) - it's not true random, but neither are the pseudo-random generators and we were just as ill-suited to guess / manipulate the condition of the random number flow given that configuration.

Comment: @ElizabethAB Thank for an inspiring comment.  In your case, however, the permutations will be rock solid reproducible. See one solution/hack below.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to first generate the samples that you would like to use and call mclapply on the samples:

```
    library("parallel")
    library("digest")

    input<-1:10
    set.seed(1)
    nsamp<-20
    ## Generate and store all the random samples
    samples<-lapply(1:nsamp, function(x){ sample(input) })

    ## apply the algorithm "diff" on every sample
    ncore0<-  lapply(samples, diff)
    ncore1<-mclapply(samples, diff, mc.cores=1)
    ncore2<-mclapply(samples, diff, mc.cores=2)
    ncore3<-mclapply(samples, diff, mc.cores=3)
    ncore4<-mclapply(samples, diff, mc.cores=4)

    ## all equal
    all.equal(ncore0,ncore1)
    all.equal(ncore0,ncore2)
    all.equal(ncore0,ncore3)
    all.equal(ncore0,ncore4)
```

This assures the reproducibility at the expense of using more memory and slightly longer running time since the computation done on each sample is typically the most time-consuming operation.

Note: The use of `mc.set.seed = F` in your question will generate the same sample for each core, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I came up with is to generate a complementary vector with seeds. `mclapply` or `lapply` iterates over the index that points both to the argument and the corresponding seed. Kind of hack, but works.

```
library("parallel")
library("digest")

input <- 1:10

# make random seed vector of length(input).
set.seed(1)
seeds <- sample.int(length(input), replace=TRUE)

f <- function(idx){ 
    # input[i] # do whatever with the input
    set.seed(seeds[idx]) # set to proper seed
    sample(1:10)}

digest(mclapply(seq_along(input), f, mc.cores=2), 'crc32')
digest(mclapply(seq_along(input), f, mc.cores=4), 'crc32')
digest(mclapply(seq_along(input), f, mc.cores=2), 'crc32')
digest(mclapply(seq_along(input), f, mc.cores=1), 'crc32')
digest(lapply(seq_along(input), f), 'crc32')
```

The issue with this trick is that when the code is wrapped the set.seed inside the function interferes with the outside set seed. For example,

```
set.seed(123)
outcome1a <- digest(mclapply(seq_along(input), f, mc.cores=4), 'crc32')
outcome1b <- digest(sample(1:10), 'crc32')

set.seed(123)
outcome2a <- digest(lapply(seq_along(input), f), 'crc32')
outcome2b <- digest(sample(1:10), 'crc32')
identical(outcome1a, outcome2a)
identical(outcome1b, outcome2b)
```

While, indeed, outcomes "a" are the same, the outcomes of stochastic computations that follow right after, that is "b" are affected and different.  I guess one hack can be to wrap the mclapply/lapply function in such a way that there is random seed generated upfront based on user input then after the execution the wrapper resets the seed to that value.

```
library("parallel")
library("digest")

wrapply <- function(input, cores){
    recover.seed <- floor(runif(1)*1e6)
    seeds <- sample.int(length(input), replace=TRUE)
    f <- function(idx){ 
        # input[i] # do whatever with the input
        set.seed(seeds[idx]) # set to proper seed
        sample(1:10)
    }
    if(is.null(cores)){
        out <- digest(lapply(seq_along(input), f), 'crc32')
    }else{
        out <- digest(mclapply(seq_along(input), f, mc.cores=cores), 'crc32')
    }
    set.seed(recover.seed)
    return(out)
}

input <- 1:10

set.seed(123)
outcome1a <- wrapply(input, cores=4)
outcome1b <- digest(sample(1:10), 'crc32')

set.seed(123)
outcome2a <- wrapply(input, cores=NULL)
outcome2b <- digest(sample(1:10), 'crc32')

identical(outcome1a, outcome2a)
identical(outcome1b, outcome2b)
```

In this case outcomes "a" and "b" are indentical.